# Maintain SelectList Options over postbacks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was wondering if there is a way to maintain your list of options on a Select List in MVC 3.  I am pretty new to MVC but in WebForms you could populate the DropDownList on the first load of the page and then the ViewState would maintain that list for all of the AutoPostBacks.  This was nice because often, DropDownLists are populated by query to the database.  I know that ViewState does not exist in MVC but is there a better way of repopulating the SelectList without having to hit the database during the request of every post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here.
Your selected value will be posted back. With that in mind since you no longer have ViewState you ideally want to

1. Have your Repository (if you dont have one - create one. You simply ask the repository for the data and it controls the caching or loading) that you ask for the data in the drop down, cache the data and just simply request it again. Rebind your list (use DropDownFor)
2. Use MVCContrib's Html.Serialize to essentially ViewState it, however the cache is a bit cleaner and doesnt rely on data sent back and forth.

Also remember that after you post your data, if everything is 'good' you want to REDIRECT back to your "GET" action to reload the data and display to the client. This was an issue in web forms that sometime a user saw XYZ after postback but after a refresh saw YXX. Using the PRG pattern in MVC posts-redirects-gets to load up fresh data.

After your post you should generally only redisplay the data if there was a validation error, otherwise redirect to a get method.

Comment: I figured that something like that would be the answer.  I guess I was just being spoiled using WebForms and Controls that maintained state with ViewState.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller receives the value on postback. You have to place that value back in the model to tell the view what the selected value is.